# how to select each row for different operation from a matrix

Tags: matlab, random

I have a sequence

```
A = 1:5
```

then I did its random permutation by

```
B = perms(A)
C = B(randperm(size(B,1)), :)
```

then I took a sample of `5` sequence randomly as follow

```
sample = C(1:5,1:4)
```

then I took a random sequence from sample as follow

```
randomRow = sample(randi(size(sample,1)),:)
```

I use the above random row for my operation. Now I am stuck how to select another row from a sample and do same operation on it, until I do operation on all rows in a sample and each row is not repeated from sample once it's processed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the below code:

```
For i=randperm(size(sample,1))
    Rand_row=sample(i,:)
    %// operate on Rand_row
End
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the same trick you used earlier with `randperm` to shuffle the rows of `sample` and then just iterate through them?

```
sample_shuffled = sample(randperm(5),:)
for s = 1:5
    randomRow = sample_shuffled(s,:)
    %// Operate on randomRow
end
```

Comment: Dan, how to put the result of each row operation in some different place so in end i can see the output of each operation i perform on each row. ?

Comment: in the loop do something like `outputs(s) = ...` but don't forget to preallocate memory for `outputs` before your loop to avoid growing the variable in the loop